# File I/O. Not able to use path of the file

Tags: c++, file-io

basically i want to be able to load text files.  This is fine.  But i want to put the text files in a folder inside the project folder.  Which is proving to be a problem because once the file is moved i cannot load it.  I have tried entering the path but i just get a run-time.  Can anybody help me with this.

Here is my code:

```
Storyline::Storyline()
{
    mStory = "Default";

}
Storyline :: Storyline(string story)
{
mStory= story;
}
void Storyline::print()
{
cout<< "Story= " << mStory<< endl;
cout<< endl;
}
void Storyline::save(ofstream& outFile)
{
outFile<< "Story = " << mStory<< endl;
outFile<< endl;
}
void Storyline::load(ifstream& inFile)
{
string garbage;
inFile>> garbage >> mStory;
}



void Storyline::Menu()
{
cout<< "\n\t******Menu******\n\n";
cout<< "Please choose one of the following:\n";
cout<< "1 -Play Game.\n";
cout<< "2 -Exit.\n";

}
void Storyline::Story(string story)
{
ifstream Story;                                                                                                     
        string line;                                                                                                            
        Story.open(story);                                                                                        
        if (Story.is_open())                                                                                
        {
                while ( Story.good() )                                                                              
                {
                        getline (Story,line);                                                                       
                        cout << line << endl;
                }
                Story.close();                                                                                           
        }
        else{
                throw("GAME FILE LOADING FAILED!");                                                             
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you correctly escape the folder slashes?

Comment: I put the file in a folder called Text Files.  My project is MaroonedCA2.  So when calling it is "Text Files\Introduction.txt"

Comment: Try escape it? "Text Files\\Introduction.txt"

Comment: Yes, That worked.  I completely forgot you needed to escape a "\".  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just for future reference: "i get a runtime" means absolutely nothing, unless you give us information about what "a runtime" means. If you get an error, please tell us what that error is, including the **exact** error message you see. It makes it much easier to help you if we know what problem you're actually having without needing to guess.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes no problem.  I will do in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save all the troubles using double slashes \\ , you can use one forward slash / instead, even under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem i had was that i didnt escape my slashes.  In C++ the slash is read for things like \n or \t.  So basically only having one \ meant nothing to the compiler.  I needed to do this: "Text File\\Introduction.txt"